# Some module of a gulp/webpack project sets extra spaces for 0\\0 for @media when compiling stylus

Tags: compilation, gulp, media-queries, stylus

Some module of a gulp/webpack project sets spaces for 0\0 for @media when compiling stylus to css

```
all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
```

and here what I get:

```
@media all and (min-width: 0 \ 0) and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) {
```

0 \ 0 is not working, only 0\0 works! Which module can add those extra spaces?
and how to eliminate them? is iy possible yo force it to take the media string the way I write it?

here are some of my project modules:

```
"eslint-loader": "^1.1.1",
"gulp-combine-mq": "^0.4.0",
"gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-stylint": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-stylus": "^2.1.0",
"merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
"stylint-stylish": "^1.2.0",
"stylus": "^0.54.5",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [css literal](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/literal.html) to prevent stylus transform your rule:

```
@css{
  @media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){
    //your css code here
  }
}
```

and you get exactly:

```
 @media all and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){
   //your css code here
 }
```

You can also use interpolation:

```
@media all and ({"min-width:0\0"}) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually that is the answer. But the problem is that yt throws an error: \node_modules\css\lib\parse\index.js:72
      throw err;
      ^
Error: undefined:3693:3: missing '}'
...
I use combineMq module that combines same @ media into a single one. Seems like it makes that crash when using @ css.

Comment: @CodeGust I add another solution, maybe works for you